# Java :: Creating a spreadsheet programmatically using latest Google Sheets v4 API

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

I have a use case where I need to fetch the Spreadsheet ID of newly created Google Spreadsheet. I referred the Google Docs and found that the method Spreadsheet.create in Google Sheets API v4 returns the Spreadsheet ID in response.

However, I am unable to get how can I use this method in Java.

Also, referring the Google Docs ([Link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration)), I got to know that I would need OAuth authorization as well. Please help me know how will I be able to setup OAuth Authorization using Java or please share if there is an existing example of the Creating a Google Spreadsheet using Java with OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) in the Sheets API docs. The Authorization part is included in the Quickstart.

Here's the snippet for the Java credentials part:

```
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
            Quickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't answered OP's problem surrounding spreadsheet ID.